# draw onDraw dispatchDraw

Tags: android, view, draw

I wonder a difference between **draw()**, **onDraw()** and **dispatchDraw()** methods in View (and ViewGroup too).

P.S. I have found [this conversation](https://plus.google.com/+ArpitMathur/posts/cT1EuBbxEgN) but it's still not clear for me. Also looks like some answers from Romain Guy has been disappeared. That's sad.

P.P.S. Good question also: *"So lets say I have a `RelativeLayout` with a button inside that has a `layoutparam` with a `margintop` of **10dip**. After measure and layout, the framework decides it should be placed **15px** below the top of the view (so `y = 15`). Now on button click, I call an animate function that animates its y position from **15** to **100**. As the value of `y` is changing if a different event causes a layout pass to happen, will the animation get interrupted and pull the button back to `y = 15`? Or does layout wait till animations complete? Or is it just the layer thats being animated so it doesnt matter?"*